# How to create multiple vectors by using loop

Tags: r

May I know how I can create multiple vector in R.
For example, if I want to create 10 vectors (v1~v10) and tried

```
for (i in 1:10)) {
paste('v',i sep = "", collapse = NULL) <- vector()
}
```

But it seems it can't work, can you advise how I can do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Make a list with 10 empty vectors. Its better than to assign 10 vectors in your global environment....
`setNames(vector('list', 10), paste0('v', 1:10))`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with `replicate` and `setNames`. The `lapply` uses the new (R 4.1.0) lambdas. Then, assign to the global environment in one instruction.

```
v <- setNames(replicate(10, vector()), paste0("v", 1:10))
#setNames(lapply(1:10, \(x) vector()), paste0("v", 1:10))
list2env(v, envir = .GlobalEnv)
ls()
# [1] "v1"  "v10" "v2"  "v3"  "v4"  "v5"  "v6"  "v7"  "v8"  "v9" 
#[11] "x"
```

A one-liner is

```
list2env(setNames(replicate(10, vector()), paste0("v", 1:10)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create 10 empty vectors, you can use the command *assign*

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  assign(paste('v',i, sep = "", collapse = NULL),vector()) 
}
```

Comment: `paste0('v',i)` is simpler.